# Cannot delete DB. Drop DB query not working

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I cannot delete database from raw MySql query here. Is there a better way? Please suggest. Is there a way to write a query to drop database in Zend. I'm using Zend 1.11

```
// Delete db function
public function deleteDB($dbName){
// For database connection
$config = new Zend_Config( 
    array(
    'database' => array(
    'adapter' => 'PDO_MYSQL',
    'params'  => array(
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'dbname'   => $dbName,
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
            )
    )
    )
);
 $db = Zend_Db::factory($config->database);

 //Delete database
 $sql = 'DROP DATABASE'. $dbName;
 $db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your configuration is correct then try to put space after `DATABASE` like

```
//Delete database
 $sql = "DROP DATABASE `". $dbName."`";
```

Comment: I've tried. It throws error as "Syntax error or access violation"

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: What is your database name?

Comment: It's a fake Db i made. "aaa-test-fake-co_fc". The db name won't matter I guess.

Comment: I updated my answer please try it. If it will work then I explain why this?

Comment: I just tried that way. It shows the same error. Can you please explain you updated answer?

Comment: It's not single quote it is back ticks can you send me what you change?

Comment: Yes, I changed it to back ticks and it worked. Thanks a lot. Thanks for being kind

Comment: One more question, can you explain why it worked? Or any links you can refer

Answer (score 0):

`$sql = 'DROP DATABASE'. $dbName;`

I think you missed a space

`$sql = 'DROP DATABASE '. $dbName;`

Comment: I've tried. It throws error as "Syntax error or access violation"

Comment: @user3386487 it seems your mysql user doesn't have privilege to drop the database

Comment: Ive just deleted db from console from same username. It seems like its a Zend issue. Can you help me on that?

Comment: @user3386487 another possibility is that the mysql user you used in php and in console is different, although they use the same name, It depends on what db hostname you connected.

Comment: @hd1-Yes, i can from xampp-shell.

Comment: Right answer is 
//Delete database
 $sql = "DROP DATABASE `". $dbName."`";
Thanks to @Sadikhasan